# Why is my timer (JS) not showing up/working?

Tags: javascript, html

Can anybody explain why my timer made with JavaScript is not showing up?
I don't know if its a problem with the HTML or the JS code. It might even be the CSS code but I don't think so.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var streamTimes = [{
      day: 1,
      hour: 19,
      minute: 0
    }, // Montag 19:00
    {
      day: 2,
      hour: 19,
      minute: 0
    }, // Dienstag 19:00
    {
      day: 3,
      hour: 19,
      minute: 0
    }, // Mittwoch 19:00
    {
      day: 4,
      hour: 19,
      minute: 0
    }, // Donnerstag 19:00
    {
      day: 5,
      hour: 20,
      minute: 0
    }, // Freitag 20:00
    {
      day: 6,
      hour: 15,
      minute: 0
    } // Samstag 15:00
  ];

  var countdownElement = document.getElementById("countdown");

  function updateCountdown() {
    var now = new Date();
    var nextStream;

    // Find next streams date
    for (var i = 0; i < streamTimes.length; i++) {
      var streamDate = getNextStreamDate(streamTimes[i].day, streamTimes[i].hour, streamTimes[i].minute);
      if (streamDate > now) {
        nextStream = streamDate;
        break;
      }
    }

    var distance = nextStream - now;

    // Timer "currently live" (If date is reached text is being shown for two hours)
    if (distance <= 0 && distance >= -7200000) {
      countdownElement.innerHTML = '<a href="https://twitch.tv/chyyyp">Stream momentan Live</a>';
      return;
    }

    // Calculation of Days, hours, minutes and seconds until next stream 
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    // Cooldown being shown here
    countdownElement.innerHTML = "Nächster Stream in: " + days + " Tage " + hours + " Stunden " + minutes + " Minuten " + seconds + " Sekunden";

    // Counting Seconds
    setTimeout(updateCountdown, 1000);
  }

  function getNextStreamDate(day, hour, minute) {
    var date = new Date();
    var daysToAdd = (day - 1 + 7 - date.getDay()) % 7;
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + daysToAdd);
    date.setHours(hour);
    date.setMinutes(minute);
    date.setSeconds(0);
    date.setMilliseconds(0);
    return date;
  }

  updateCountdown();
};
```

```css
/* global */

body {
  font-family: 'Varela Round', Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #111;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
}

h1,
h2 {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

p {
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}


/* header */

header {
  background-color: #222;
  padding: 20px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
  margin: 0;
}


/* main */

main {
  padding: 20px;
  max-width: 600px;
}

section {
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  padding-top: 20px;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease;
}

section:first-child {
  padding-top: 0;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 20px;
}


/* divider */

.divider {
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  margin-bottom: -1em;
  /* Geändert von 1em zu -1em */
}


/* Hover-effect */

section:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

section:not(:hover) {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

section:not(:hover) h2,
section:not(:hover) p {
  transform: scale(0.9);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Varela+Round&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<header>
  <h1>Der Streamplan</h1>
</header>

<main>
  <div class="divider"></div>
  <section>
    <h2>Montag</h2>
    <p>19:00 - 21:00 Uhr</p>
  </section>
  <div class="divider"></div>
  <section>
    <h2>Dienstag</h2>
    <p>19:00 - 21:00 Uhr</p>
  </section>
  <div class="divider"></div>
  <section>
    <h2>Mittwoch</h2>
    <p>19:00 - 21:00 Uhr</p>
  </section>
  <div class="divider"></div>
  <section>
    <h2>Donnerstag</h2>
    <p>19:00 - 21:00 Uhr</p>
  </section>
  <div class="divider"></div>
  <section>
    <h2>Freitag</h2>
    <p>20:00 - 24:00 Uhr</p>
  </section>
  <div class="divider"></div>
  <section>
    <h2>Samstag</h2>
    <p>15:00 - 18:00 Uhr</p>
  </section>
  <div class="divider"></div>
  <section>
    <h2>Sonntag</h2>
    <p>Kein Stream</p>
  </section>
  <div class="divider"></div>
</main>
```

Comment: Well this is just a first look for 5 secs on your code: I cannot find any html container element named "countdown" in your html code nor you are adding it to the document somewhere by using javascript. 
The result is your reference you are trying to apply here:
var countdownElement = document.getElementById("countdown");
will not have a value and thus is empty.
So my suggestion is to add a container div like this <div id="countdown">xxx</div> in html
OR 
add one per javascript like this:
var myDiv = document.createElement('div');
myDiv.setAttribute("id", "countdown");
Hope this helps.

Comment: On a sidenote, don't use `window.onload`, put your script in its own script file, and then load that with `<script src="..." async defer></script>` so that the script loads in parallel with everything else, but doesn't _execute_ until the DOM has been constructed and anything that needs to tie into the page itself can actually succeed. Also, stop using `var`, use `let` or `const` depending on whether you need to reassign a value to a variable or not (both of which use normal block scoping rules, unlike `var`, which doesn't behave the way you expect at all and is _function_ scoped).

Answer (score 0):

@Freddy is correct; there is no element with the id of `countdown` in DOM or html. Add it somewhere in your html and then it appears to be working.

```
<div id="countdown"></div>
```